# How can I filter 2 object arrays in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
const obj1 = [{'food': ['apple'], 'drink': ['wine', 'juice']}];

const obj2 = [{id: 1, 'food': ['apple'], dummy: 'test', 'drink':['wine', 'juice']}, 
              {id: 2, 'food': 'banana', dummy: 'test', 'drink':['juice']},
              {id: 3, 'food': ['apple', 'banana'], dummy: 'test'},'drink':['juice']}
              ];


//and result should be like this
const result = [{id:1, 'food': ['apple'], 'drink': ['wine', 'juice']}];
```

if there's two object arrays, how can I filter obj1 on obj2?
What I'm going to do is

1. if obj1 has same value with obj2, leave obj2's objects that contains same
   value with obj1.
2. set the state with those remained objects.

this is how I tried.
the problem of this logic is
returned value contains only filtered value. 
ex) {food:['banana]}
but It has to return all object that contain 'banana', not only 'banana'.
(so that I can set State with filtered result)

```js
//key arg is recived key from outside. (it should be 'food' or 'drink')

const showFilteredRes = (obj1, key) => {
    let filteredRes = {};

    obj2.forEach((obj2) => {
      for (let filters in obj1) {
        for (let infos in obj2) {
          if (filters === infos) {
            filteredRes[infos] = obj2[key];
            console.log(filteredRes);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

how can I develop this code?

I edited my example because my explanation was too poor.

Comment: Loop through an array and compare with deep equal.

Comment: You should give some examples of inputs and desired outputs to make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const obj1 = [{
  'food': ['banana'],
  'drink': ['wine', 'juice']
}];

const obj2 = [{
    id: 1,
    'food': ['apple', 'custard'],
    dummy: 'test',
    'drink': ['wine', 'juice']
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    'food': ['banana'],
    dummy: 'test',
    'drink': ['juice']
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    'food': ['apple', 'banana'],
    dummy: 'test',
    'drink': ['juice', 'wine']
  }
];


const showFilteredRes = (filtered, key) => {
  let result = [];
  filtered.forEach((filteredObj) => {
    obj2.forEach((obj) => {
      if (JSON.stringify(obj[key]) == JSON.stringify(filteredObj[key])) {
        result.push(obj);
      }
    })
  })
  console.log(result);
};

showFilteredRes(obj1, "food");
```

Looping though the first Object and acquire the desired object using the deep compare arrays with same key.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) :

```
const showFilteredRes = (filtered, key) => {
    let filteredRes = {};
    obj2.forEach(entry => {
    if(entry[key].some(item => obj1[key].includes(item)))
    {
        console.log(filteredRes);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think some() is not a good way in this case. because It returns true when It found matched value. but In my case, even the method found the matched case, It still has to search until array ends

Comment: Why do you think so? Please provide reasons.

Comment: first of all, some() returns boolean type of data. but I need filtered object. and secondly, let me say If I put 'apple' for keyword and there's 5 object arrays to search. but If first object array has 'apple' value then some() method

Comment: would stop searching and return true.